# Android, Realm: Why method isClosed() return false?

Tags: android, realm

Realm 3.5.0

I added Realm in MyApp.

Here snippet:

```
public class MainApp extends MultiDexApplication {    
    private void setRealmDefaultSyncConfiguration(SyncUser syncUser, String realmURL) {
        SyncConfiguration sync = new SyncConfiguration.Builder(syncUser, realmURL).build();
            Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(sync );
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                Log.d(TAG, "setRealmDefaultSyncConfiguration: SUCCESS SET REALM DEFAULT CONFIGURATION:"
                        + "\nThreadSignature = " + AndroidUtil.getThreadSignature()
                        + "\nsyncUser = " + syncUser
                        + "\nrealmURL = " + realmURL
                        + "\nRealm = " + Realm.getDefaultInstance()
                        + "\nRealmget. DefaultConfiguration:\n\n" + Realm.getDefaultInstance().getConfiguration() + "\n\n"
                );
    }
}
```

Here's the logcat data:

```
 setRealmDefaultSyncConfiguration: SUCCESS SET REALM DEFAULT CONFIGURATION:
 Thread=main: id=1, priority=5, group=main
 syncUser = {UserId: 32afeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee3c63f5606c4b, AuthUrl: http://172.12.11.90:9080/auth, IsValid: true, Sessions: 0}
 realmURL = realm://172.12.11.90:9080/fccc46ssssssssssssssssb9e828700c/db
 Realm = io.realm.Realm@4225bd68
 Realmget. DefaultConfiguration:  
 realmDirectory: /data/data/com.myproject/files/realm-object-server/32afeeeee/fccc46bbe2354bae35d3ddb9e828700c
 realmFileName : db
 canonicalPath: /data/data/com.myproject/files/realm-object-server/32afeeeee3f5606c4b/fccc46ssssssssssssssssb9e828700c/db
 key: [length: 0]
 schemaVersion: 0
 migration: null
 deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded: false
 durability: FULL
 schemaMediator: io.realm.DefaultRealmModuleMediator@42136c40
 readOnly: false
 compactOnLaunch: null
 serverUrl: realm://172.12.11.90:9080/fccc46ssssssssssssssssb9e828700c/db
 user: {UserId: 32afeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee3c63f5606c4b,
 AuthUrl: http://172.12.11.90:9080/auth, IsValid: true, Sessions: 0}
 errorHandler: io.realm.SyncManager$1@42068038
 deleteRealmOnLogout: false
 waitForInitialRemoteData: true
```

As you can see the Realm in create on the "main" thread.

PersonFragment code:

```
public class PersonsFragment extends Fragment {
    private Realm realm;

    @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.organizations_fragment, container, false);
            realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            return rootView;
        }        

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy():"
                    + "\nThreadSignature=" + AndroidUtil.getThreadSignature()
                    + "\nRealm global instance=" + Realm.getGlobalInstanceCount(Realm.getDefaultConfiguration())
                    + "\nrealm=" + realm);
        realm.close();
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy():"
                    + "\nThreadSignature=" + AndroidUtil.getThreadSignature()
                    + "\nrealm.isClosed()=" + realm.isClosed()
                    + "\nRealm global instance=" + Realm.getGlobalInstanceCount(Realm.getDefaultConfiguration())
            );
    }
}
```

The logcat of my fragment:

```
PersonsFragment(18573):onDestroy():
PersonsFragment(18573):Thread=main:id=1,priority=5,group=main
PersonsFragment(18573):Realm global instance = 1
PersonsFragment(18573):realm = io.realm.Realm@4225bd68  
PersonsFragment(18573):onDestroy():
PersonsFragment(18573):Thread=main:id=1,priority=5,group=main
PersonsFragment(18573):realm.isClosed() = false
PersonsFragment(18573):Realm global instance = 1
```

As you can see the **isClose()** is still *false* and **Realm global instance** is always = 1, also that the Realm instance is created on the **Main** thread.

Comment: Try You set Log above realm.close();

Comment: Are you creating an Instance of Realm on a different thread as well?

Comment: A Realm is thread local with an instance counter, so every time you call `Realm.getInstance()` the counter will increase by one. The Realm will not fully close until the the counter reaches 0 again (= you called `realm.close()`  on all your instances).

Comment: See https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#controlling-the-lifecycle-of-realm-instances and https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#closing-realm-instances

Comment: See my addition info above.

Comment: `globalCount` gives you number of threads a Realm is opened on, so most likely you have a background thread somewhere with an open Realm.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**
I just found this issue [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/5069)

Or you can follow this -

You can try this, from what I've learnt from this [issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3321). You might have multiple Realm instances open, on a different thread, you can try using the code below, to close every instance of Realm in the `onDestroy()` -

```
while(!realm.isClosed()) realm.close();
```

And then check if the `isClosed()` returns true or not.

Also to handle Realm instance on a different thread in a better way you can follow @Zhuinden's approach -

```
try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
   // use realm
} // auto-close
```

Or close the Realm instance in the `finally` block.

Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: Note that closing a Realm like that in a loop means you don't have a full understanding of where your Realm instances are and mean that you risk running into an `IllegalStateException` elsewhere.